# Adding additional DIV input based on user input in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm creating function where user will insert number of value. And additional div of input will appear based the number of value of user have input previous div.

example

```
Insert number of user : `2`
```

Additional input based on number of user input

```
name :
name :
```

If user put `3` there will be `3` name and if user change it into `2` there will be `2` name.

How do I fix it in order to achieve the `example` that  I want.

```js
     $('#user').hide();
        $("#user_num").change(function()
        {
            $("#user").remove();
            let m = $(this).val();
                for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(m); i++){
                  $('#user').show();
              
                }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="info">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30">
        <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span><i>Insert number of user </i></b></label><br>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <input class="from-control" type="number" placeholder="2" id="user_num" required >
            </div>
    </div>
                                                                 
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="user">
        <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span><i> Name </i></b></label><br>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <input class="from-control" type="text" id="name" required >
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where close to achieve it with your attempt. You needed to implement an event handler that executes a function when the input field value is changed. You can achieve this with `.on('change', function(){ // do something })`

Every time the function is executed it clears the html inside `<div id="inputs-container"></div>` and the loop appends html code to that div `n` times.

### Try the following snippet

```js
$('#in').on('change', function(){

  let n = $(this).val()
  let html_code = 'name: <input value="" style="margin-top:5px"><br>'; 

  $('#inputs-container').html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
         $('#inputs-container').append(html_code);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info" style="margin:10px">
    
  Insert number of users: <input id="in" value="" /> 
  
  <div id="inputs-container" style="margin-top:20px"> 
  </div>

</div>
```

> Note: I updated the jQuery CDN to the latest one. You where using an
> older version.

Comment: would it be possible to do it without a button ? Taking example like this one ? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7PhJZ/37/)

Comment: yes, instead of using `on('click')` use `on('change')` ... I changed the snippet, try it out

Comment: Your welcome. Always use the latest version of jQuery, this is very important. You where using a version really old and lots of method don't work.